# When the argument is null as a parameter

Tags: java, spring-mvc

The method as a controller in Java that I have written gets an File typed argument like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/insertUser")
public String insertUser(@RequestParam("imageFile") CommonsMultipartFile file,
        HttpSession session) throws Exception {
......}
```

What my problem is that when there is no File argument sent from a JSP , how I can handle it.
I am not sure if my explain was understandable though.

Comment: Try `required = false`

Answer (score 4):

You can set `defaultValue` to handle `null` case:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/insertUser")
public String insertUser(@RequestParam(value = "imageFile",  required = false, defaultValue = "/default/path/to/file") CommonsMultipartFile file,
        HttpSession session) throws Exception {
......}
```

Comment: That's a feature that would be so useful in Java!

Comment: thank you for the help. But I also had to make a file null check like if(file.getSize() != 0){.....

Comment: You can just set `required=false` if no argument is sent, then it will be null. Then you can do these validations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to make it as optional you can do

```
 @RequestParam(value = "imageFile", required = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/insertUser")
public String insertUser(@RequestParam("imageFile") CommonsMultipartFile file,
        HttpSession session) throws Exception {

        if(file!=null && !file.isEmpty()) {
           //file is uploaded successfully
        } else {
           //file is not uploaded
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `required = false` for `imageFile`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/insertUser")
public String insertUser(@RequestParam("imageFile", required = false) CommonsMultipartFile file,HttpSession session) throws Exception {
......}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is whether you can provide an optional parameter as request param, you can do that by simply changing your @RequestParam to below.

```
@RequestParam(value = "imageFile", required = false) CommonsMultipartFile file
```

If you are using Java 8 you can also do the below.

```
@RequestParam("imageFile") Optional<CommonsMultipartFile> file
```

If your question is not this then please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do this parameter as `required = false` so that you have option to sand this parameter or not.

```
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/insertUser")
    public String insertUser(@RequestParam(value="imageFile",required=false) CommonsMultipartFile file,
        HttpSession session) throws Exception {
......}
}
```

using this, if you send "imageFile" then you will get on server, else you have not send "imageFile" then you will get it null.